# Why does my code work with height:100px, but not height:100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Following is the piece of code that gets more content from DB when scrolled down. Its mainly JQuery.

I don't understand why it works when height is changed as 100px, but it doesn't work when height is given as 100% or auto.

```
<div id="contentBox" style="overflow: scroll;width: 200px; height: 100px;">
  <div id="actualContent">
    <p>
      <span>2</span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare facilisis mollis. Etiam non sem massa, a gravida nunc. Mauris lectus augue, posuere at viverra sed, dignissim sed libero. 
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>3</span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare facilisis mollis. Etiam non sem massa, a gravida nunc. Mauris lectus augue, posuere at viverra sed, dignissim sed libero.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

$("#contentBox").scroll(function(){
  if($("#contentBox").scrollTop() >= ($("#actualContent").height() - $("#contentBox").height())){
       alert("Hi");
     }
 });
```

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/8qv2ch9u/

How to make it work without height 100px, but the content filling the size of the browser?

Comment: Because if the height is 100% or auto then it's by definition at least as high as its contents. Add `html, body { height:100% }` to your CSS.

Comment: How to make it work without height 100px, but the content filling the size of the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `height: 100px`, the element knows exactly what it needs to do.

With `height: 100%`, the element needs to know: *percentage of what?*

For percentage heights, you need to provide a frame of reference. This is done by specifying the height of the parent. And if the parent of `#contentBox` is also a percentage, then the grandparent would need an explicit height, as well.

Basically, if you're going to use percentage heights, you need to specify the heights for all parent elements up to and including the root element:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8qv2ch9u/3/

Here's the relevant section from the spec:

> [**W3C `height` property definition**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height):
>
> **percentage**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.
>
> **auto**
>  The height depends on the values of other properties.

See also:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided is wrong answer. I want the content to be on full browser. It still has height as 100px and when I remove 100px for ContentBox, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, you revised your question while I was preparing my answer. I've revised my answer, as well. Cheers!

Comment: What do you want to happen to content that overflows the container? Or is the container just supposed to expand as necessary?

Comment: I want it to be like Quora home page after you login. I want the overflowing content to be shown.

Comment: Why not just remove all `height` rules, allowing the height to always be based on content size? https://jsfiddle.net/8qv2ch9u/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102116/discussion-between-user3705478-and-michael-b).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by michael you can set `body` height, point is to set height of element in percentage it must have a parent element from whom it will be getting percentage height. Or try the whole code in another div(parent element) and set height in pixels for parent element, then height of child element can be set to percentage of parent element. Check this simple snippet.

```css
.parent{width:50px;height:600px;}
.childone{width:100%;height:80%;background-color:red;}
.childtwo{width:100%;height:19%;background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='childone'>I have 80% height of my parent</div>
  <div class='childtwo'>i have 19% height of my parent</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `100px` to `100vh` for view height, or `vw` for view width.